How do i restart all of my sequences on PostgreSQL
I'm currently trying to figure out a way to restart all of my sequences (40 in total) to 2. But i don't have a single clue on how to do it.
I have this command to change a single sequence back to 2, but I would need to execute it for every single sequence. I wanted a command I could use to restart all 40 sequences in on go.
ALTER SEQUENCE abastecimentos_controle_seq RESTART WITH 2;

I'll be glad with any help you guys can provide me with!

Create a stored procedure, using dynamic sql, which contains the code to restart those sequences.  (Use the info from this Q/A: \d+ information_schema.sequences )

What is the point of doing that?

If you're really using 9.5, consider an update. 9.5 support ended in 2021.

Connect to PostgreSQL using psql and run the following command:
SELECT format(
          'ALTER SEQUENCE %s RESTART WITH 2;',
          oid::regclass
       )
FROM pg_class
WHERE relkind = 'S' \gexec

\gexec executes every line of the query result as SQL statement.

\gexec was added to psql in 9.6. But I think a newer client shouldn't have a problem using it against OP's 9.5 db.
